# Ajax post is empty

Tags: php, ajax

I have a (searchresult.php) in the (index.php), which I trying to use ajax post from (searchresult.php) to pass and ID back to (index.php), however $_POST["dataid"] keep showing an empty result, but console log show result has sent through. Can anybody pls help me, I have been stuck for almost 2 months. I appreciate that anybody can help me. thank you.

searchresult.php

```
<a onClick="openoverlay(<?php echo $data["ID"]?>)"><?php echo $data["ID"]?><a>
```

index.php

```
function openoverlay(dataid) {
        var myData = 'dataid='+dataid;
        $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"text",
        data:myData, //Pass your varibale in data
        success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert(dataid); //you get return value in this varibale, us it anywhere
        }
        });
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "block";
}  
function closeoverlay() {
          document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "none";
}



<div id="myNav" class="overlay">

          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeoverlay()">&times;</a>

          <div class="overlay-content">

                    <div style=" background:#F00; width:100px; height:100px; color:#FFF; border-color:#ff0; border-width:1px; border-style:solid;">
                    <?php echo $_POST["dataid"]; ?> 
                    </div>

                    <a href="#">About </a>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                    <a href="#">Clients</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202933/discussion-on-question-by-eug-ajax-post-is-empty).

Comment: The alert shows that `dataid` is filled in, I don't see a problem with `searchresult.php`.

Comment: is an very large piece of array code from the map marker, which has iniviudal ID value, i have to make a link where user can click to see more image, but first i need the value to pass through

Comment: and after i have the value i can do mysql query

Comment: All users who have participated will automatically have access to the chat room.